# why filtering then mapping changes the original array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const words = [{ref : "a", list: "a & b & c & d", total: 0},
              {ref : "a", list: "a & b & c & d", total: 0},
              {ref : "b", list: "aa & bb & cc & dd", total: 0},
              {ref : "c", list: "aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd", total: 0}];

 var data = words.filter(item => {
            if (item.ref == "a")
              return item;
        });

let result = data.map(o => {
            o.list = o.list.split('&').map(key => ({
                selected: false,
            }))
            return o;
        });
console.log(words);
console.log(result);
```

- I have words array
- after filtering for `ref : a` i'm getting new array `data`
- but when i modifiy the `data`'s  object it is reflecting on main array `words`'s.
  which should not happen.

```
words
> Array [
Object { ref: "a", list: Array [Object { selected: false }, Object { selected: false }] },
Object { ref: "a", list: Array [Object { selected: false }, Object { selected: false }] },
Object { ref: "b", list: "aa & bb" },
Object { ref: "c", list: "aaa & bbb" }
]

result
> Array [
Object { ref: "a", list: Array [Object { selected: false }, Object { selected: false }] },
Object { ref: "a", list: Array [Object { selected: false }, Object { selected: false }] }
]
```

- In words you can see `ref b` and `ref c` is not modified
- but `ref a` is changed. which should not happen in my case

*** How to avoid alteration of original array `words` ? ***

Comment: `map` returns a new array. But, here `o.list = o.list.split()` you are modifying the objects inside the array. You can change it to something like `data.map(o => ({ ...o, list:o.list.split('&') }) )`. Also, you can simplify filter to: `words.filter(item => item.ref == "a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` call changes the `list` property of the original object. `map()` returns a new array, but if you change the objects inside it directly, they are affected. Objects are always passed by a reference.

To prevent your `map()` changing the original array, you need to return a copy of each element:

```js
let result = data.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    points: 10,
    list: o.list.split('&').map(key => ({
        selected: false,
    }))
}));
```

Of note, you also use `filter()` wrong. In `filter()`, you should return `true` or `false` to, respectively, keep or reject an element. It's enough to return the result of your condition:

```js
var data = words.filter(item => {
    return item.ref == "a";
});
```

Comment: you didn't answered my question `How to avoid alteration of original array words ? `

Comment: this `return item.ref == "a";` doesn't answer my question

Comment: I did answer your question, read my entire answer carefully.

Comment: ok, you edited your answer many times. which i did't seen. thank you

Comment: I edited once to add the snippet how to fix your `map()`. The answer why it's behaving like that was there from the start. But thanks.

Comment: hey, i have one more field `total` along with `list`, how to update that number. its not object like list.

Comment: I don't know where you have it. Can you update your question?

Comment: Kindly look.... i updated

Comment: And what do you want to do with that `total`? With my answer, it's stays there being `0`.

Comment: @ Robo Robok i'm working on a live module. where i need to show total dynamically. can you please show me how to do that

Comment: The total of what? You didn't say.

Comment: its the total number of points user have. So, i'm capturing that in my project.

Comment: just update it to 10. thank you

Comment: Updated, take a look.